# how do you implement groovy right shift overload operator when java uses pass by value references

Tags: groovy, operator-overloading

having a bad brain day.  I'm trying to implement the >> right shift operator for a class and want this to output a variable from within the class

```
class SomeImplClass () {....
def rightShift (evalResult){
    evalResult = this.evaluate()
    println "rightShift : outputiing  $evalResult"
    this
}
```

and use like

```
def res
def im = new SomeImplClass(); im >> res
```

as res is passed by value, this works within the body of the right shift, but when you come out to the caller, res does not get set - it still points to original memory address.

so how doe you implement the right shift to change the value pointed by a variable in the outer scope?

Answer (score 0):

Only way I could find to do this is to pass a closure as parameter to right shift then call that closure with the value you want to send out

As the closure comes with its birthday context you can process the paramwater you pass to that closure to set a variable that the closure has access to via its context.